# File uploading progress issue

Tags: ios, swift, afhttpsessionmanager

I am uploading a single file in a table view cell using AFNetworking.

Uploading is working alright. But when I scroll my cell off view, the progress is gone or some times it displays different progress values like 20% or 50%, and again 30%.

This is my code:

```
   //Tableview Cell configure
    var cell :  ChattingPhotoCell!
                if message.vendorType == .Receiver {
                    //Receive Image message
                    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceiveChattingPhotoCell") as! ChattingPhotoCell
                    if cell == nil {
                        cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ReceiveChattingPhotoCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! ChattingPhotoCell
                    }
                    cell.reloadDelegate = self
                    cell.mDelegate = self
                    cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
                    cell.conficureImageCell(msg: message,indexPath: indexPath)
                } else {
                    // Send Image Message
                    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SenderChattingPhotoCell") as! ChattingPhotoCell
                    if cell == nil {
                        cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SenderChattingPhotoCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! ChattingPhotoCell
                    }
                    cell.reloadDelegate = self
                    cell.mDelegate = self
                    cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
                    cell.conficureImageCell(msg: message,indexPath: indexPath)
                }
    //MyCell code
    
        func conficureImageCell(msg:Message,indexPath:IndexPath) {
                self.message = msg
                self.indexPath = indexPath
                if self.message.vendorType == .Sender {
                    self.senderCellConfigure()
                } else {
                    self.receiverCellConfigure()
                }
            }

// sender configure methods
        func senderCellConfigure() {     
        // Send Message
        if message.upload ==  1 {
            self.btnRetry.isHidden = true
        }else{
            self.btnRetry.isHidden = false
        }
        
        if message.is_send == 0 && !self.message.isUploadMedia && message.upload != 1 {
            let image = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: documentDir.path)
            if image != nil {
                self.uploadImageToServer(ArrImage_Video: NSMutableArray.init(array: [image!]), strMsgType: "3")
            }
        }
        
        if self.message.isUploadMedia {
            self.progressView.isHidden = false
            self.btnRetry.isHidden = true
        } else {
            self.progressView.isHidden = true
        }
        

    }


   
     // MARK:- WebserviceCalling // Hiren
        func uploadImageToServer(ArrImage_Video:NSMutableArray,strMsgType: String){
            self.message.isUploadMedia = true
            self.btnRetry.isHidden = true
            if self.str_media_url.isBlank {
                self.progressView.isHidden = false
                let accessToken = Singleton.sharedSingleton.retriveFromUserDefaults(key:Global.kLoggedInUserKey.AccessToken)
                print(accessToken!)
                let param: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
                param.setValue(fromJID, forKey: "from_user_id")
                param.setValue(toJID, forKey: "to_user_id")
                param.setValue(strMsgType, forKey: "message_type")
                param.setValue("ABC", forKey: "from_user_name")
                param.setValue(UIDevice.current.model, forKey: "device_type")
                param.setValue("897584acac541d73d5f01f294fe944ddb35b6f67ea894e9ac29b03c7da69ca48", forKey: "device_token")
                param.setValue("jpeg", forKey: "file_type")
                param.setValue("135", forKey: "message_id")
                param.setValue(accessToken, forKey: "access_token")
                
                AFAPIMaster.sharedAPIMaster.PostMediatoServer_chat(params: param, arrMedia: ArrImage_Video, showLoader: false, enableInteraction: true, viewObj: self, onSuccess: {
                    (DictResponse) in
                    let dictResponse: NSDictionary = DictResponse as! NSDictionary
                    let dictData: NSDictionary = dictResponse.object(forKey: "SuccessResponse") as! NSDictionary
                    let media_url = dictData.object(forKey: "media_url") as? String ?? ""
                    let media_id = dictData.object(forKey: "id") as? Int ?? 0
                    let thumb_image = dictData.object(forKey: "thumb_image") as? String ?? ""
                    print(media_url)
                    print(thumb_image)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.progressView.isHidden = true
                        let onChatMaster = OnChatMasterTable()
                        let messageObj = onChatMaster.getMessageFromDB(strMessageID: self.msgID, strFromUId: self.fromJID, strToUId: self.toJID)
                        messageObj.media_url = media_url
                        messageObj.thumb_url = thumb_image
                        messageObj.upload = 1
                        messageObj.message = self.imageName
                        messageObj.media_id = media_id
                        self.str_media_ID = String(media_id)
                        self.message.media_id = media_id
                        DBHelper.sharedInstance.queue?.inDatabase() {
                            db in
                            DBHelper.sharedInstance.chilaxDB.open()
                            let strUpdQuery = "UPDATE OnChat_Master SET upload = 1 , media_url = '\(media_url)', thumb_url = '\(thumb_image)' , media_id = \(media_id) where message_id = '\(messageObj.message_id)' AND from_user_id = '\(messageObj.from_user_id)' AND to_user_id = '\(messageObj.to_user_id)'"
                            DBHelper.sharedInstance.chilaxDB.executeUpdate(strUpdQuery, withArgumentsIn: [])
                            DBHelper.sharedInstance.chilaxDB.close()
                        }
                        //onChatMaster.updateMessageInDB(messsageObj: messageObj)
                        self.sendMediaDataToSender(media_url: media_url, thumb_image: thumb_image,strMediaId:self.str_media_ID)
                        self.message.isUploadMedia = false
                    }
                }, displayProgress: {
                    (progress) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let progressTask : Float = Float((progress as! Progress).fractionCompleted)
                        print(progressTask)
                        self.progressView.setProgress(progressTask, animated: true)
                    }
                }, onFailure: {
                    self.progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
                    self.progressView.isHidden = true
                    self.btnRetry.isHidden = false
                    self.message.isUploadMedia = false
                })
            
        } else {
            self.sendMediaDataToSender(media_url: str_media_url, thumb_image: str_thumb_url, strMediaId: str_media_ID)
        }
    }
```

I reuse cell using table view deque methods. Any wrong in this code.

Comment: Could you please add cellForRow method ?

Comment: @MikeAlter Please check code.

Comment: @ilesh I would need to understand your code first. Should not the property message and progressView be different for different cells? Otherwise how will you handle the case when there are multiple upload cells simultaneously. self.message looks incorrect. Can you post more code?

Comment: @kerry Thaks for your interest. I will post all the code.